# Squaring multi-dimensional array, including cross term, without for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to square a particular axis of a multi dimensional array without using loop in python.

Here I will present the code with loop.

First, let's define a simple array

```
x = np.random.randint(1, size=(2, 3))
```

Since the value of the second axis is 3, we have x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>. The square term of this array is x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>, x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>, x<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup>, 2x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub>, 2x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>3</sub>, 2x<sub>2</sub>x<sub>3</sub>. In total, we have 9 terms.

Here is the full code:

```
import numpy as np
import time

x = np.random.randint(low=20, size=(2, 3))
print(x)

a, b = x.shape
for i in range(b):
    XiXj = np.einsum('i, ij->ij', x[:, i], x[:, i:b])
    x = np.concatenate((x, XiXj) , axis=1)

print(x)
```

Print:

```
[[ 3 12 18]
 [12 10 10]]
[[  3  12  18   9  36  54 144 216 324]
 [ 12  10  10 144 120 120 100 100 100]]
```

Of course, this won't take long to compute. However, one may have the size of the array of [2000, 5000]. This will take awhile to compute.

How would you do it without the for loop?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your question?

Comment: Hi, my question is can I square the variable like above without loop? Thanks:)